# Android Bottom Navigation

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have been implementing a bottom navigation bar into my app, the problem is no matter which activity I am on the dashboard icon is the highlighted one. How do I get it so whichever activity I am on is the highlighted one?

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity
    implements View.OnClickListener
{

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.navigation_request:
                Intent r = new Intent(Dashboard.this, Request.class);
                startActivity(r);
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_settings:
                Intent s = new Intent(Dashboard.this, AppSettings.class);
                startActivity(s);
                finish();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}
```

Here is my XML Menu file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_home" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_request"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_request_icon"
    android:title="@string/title_request" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_settings"
    android:title="@string/title_settings" />

</menu>
```

Here is how I use the navigation in my activity_dashboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<!-- ONLY TEXTVIEWS ARE HERE -->

</FrameLayout>



<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is the bottom navigation view visible on the other activities you open (Request and AppSettings)? Or do you mean that _when you return to Dashboard_ the same item is always checked?

Comment: All three activities has this same exact code, and no matter which one I go to Dashboard is always highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using many different `Activity` instances that all duplicate the `BottomNavigationView` and its associated code (like the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` etc) is not recommended. Instead, you would generally use a single `Activity` that hosts the `BottomNavigationView` as well as multiple `Fragment` instances that are `.replace()`d into your content area as the user interacts with the `BottomNavigationView`.

That being said, let's see if we can solve your problem.

There are two pieces to this puzzle. The first is simple: you have to indicate which item in your `BottomNavigationView` should be selected. This can be achieved by calling `setSelectedItemId()`. Add something like this to your `onCreate()` method.

```
    navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_settings);
```

The second is a little more complicated. When you call `setSelectedItemId()`, the system is going to behave as though a user had tapped on that item. In other words, your `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` will be triggered.

Looking at your posted listener, I notice that you always `return false`. If you check the documentation for `onNavigationItemSelected()`, you will find

> **Returns**:
>   `true` to display the item as the selected item and `false` if the item should not be selected

So the call to `setSelectedItemId()` won't work without also changing your listener to return `true`.

You could still solve the problem with just a `setSelectedItemId()` call if you place that call **before** your `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener()` call, but that's just masking the problem. It'd be better to fix your listener to return `true` in cases where you want the tapped item to appear as selected.

Comment: I tried that and got the same result. Still only shows the dashboard activity highlighted.

Comment: Then there is some other problem. I created an app that only has a BottonNavigationView with a menu that has two items. If all I do in my MainActivity is call `setContentView()` then the first item is highlighted, but if I add a `findViewById()` and `setSelectedItemId()`, the second item is highlighted.

Comment: Well I found out if I comment out this line `navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);` then it does what you suggested, but then the on click doesn't work.

Comment: @Jayce I've updated my answer. Your navigation listener will have to return `true` for items to be displayed as selected.

Answer (score 1):

**Step - 1 put below code into app level Build.gradle**

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
```

**Step - 2 put below code into activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Step - 3 put below code into menu/bottom_nav_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="Orders" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="Services" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_account"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="Account" />
</menu>
```

**Step - 4 put below code into MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.bottomnavigationdemo.ui.account.AccountFragment;
import com.example.bottomnavigationdemo.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment;
import com.example.bottomnavigationdemo.ui.home.HomeFragment;
import com.example.bottomnavigationdemo.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                                .commit();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
                        transaction.commit();
                        return true;

                    case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                        Fragment fragment2 = new DashboardFragment();
                        transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment2, fragment2.getClass().getSimpleName());

                        transaction.commit();
                        return true;

                    case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                        Fragment fragment3 = new NotificationsFragment();
                        transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment3, fragment3.getClass().getSimpleName());
                        transaction.commit();
                        return true;

                    case R.id.navigation_account:
                        Fragment fragment4 = new AccountFragment();
                        transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment4, fragment4.getClass().getSimpleName());
                        transaction.commit();
                        return true;
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
    }

}
```

**Step - 5 put below code into HomeFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.example.bottomnavigationdemo.R;
import com.example.bottomnavigationdemo.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return root;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use method `setSelectedItemId(int id)` which let's you mark an item as selected as if it was tapped.

Like this:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) 
findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.my_menu_item_id);
```